No binding to D1 in Astro and Cloudflare on build
I have Astro app with connection to D1 database using Cloudflare and wrangler.
According to this tutorial (but using Framework starter - Astro):
I created database, added d1 binding in wrangler.toml, added some data, tested data and it's fine.
Then I added D1 to environment variables in env.d.ts
/// <reference path="../.astro/types.d.ts" />

type Env = {
  DB: D1Database;
};

type Runtime = import('@astrojs/cloudflare').Runtime<Env>;

declare namespace App {
  interface Locals extends Runtime {}
}


I created minimal api endpoint:
import type { APIRoute } from "astro";

export const prerender = false;
export const GET: APIRoute = async (context) => {
  const db = context.locals.runtime.env.DB;

  // console.log(context.locals.runtime.env);

  const customer = await db.prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers").first();

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(customer));
};


and I call it in Astro component
---
import { GET } from './api.json';

const response = await GET(Astro);
const ballads = await response.json();
---

<main>
    <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(ballads, null, 2)}
    </pre>
</main>

Now when I run this locally (astro dev) still everything is correct, but when I try to build my app (astro check && astro build) command exits with error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prepare'):

I see that env.DB is undefined. Why? Did I miss something?
I even console.log my environment variables (in endpoint as in code snippet) and locally I see that DB is here

but on build I see my computer variable (and no DB). Is this correct? Maybe this is a hint.

I deployed my database and added another binding (to the same database) under [[env.preview.d1_databases]] in wrangler.toml but didn't help.
EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I am using 'hybrid' mode rendering output.
Now I see that my endpoint has prerender property set to false and my component don't have this property (so it's set to true) and I can agree that this can be problematic. I see it works only when I set prerender to false in both places but I do insist on component to have prerender set to true. Is it possible?
So my question is: Can I have prerendered Astro component with a call to endpoint with query to database (D1 using wrangler)?

why are you doing await GET(Astro) instead of calling db.prepare directly? (or just importing a helper function with the db code.) Quite possible the context is lost because of that.

@mb21 I've tried calling db.prepare directly but it didn't helped. The result was the same :/

So I asked this question on Astro's Discord and get this answer: "it is possible, but you need to bind to the remote database if you want to use production data", "that needs a second terminal process and custom wrangler cli command.. it's true that it is not that easy to do today"
Anyway I decided to switch my database to Turso + drizzle and now I don't have to worry about this.
